# Not able to upload phpunit Laravel files on cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, cpanel, virus

I am not able to upload phpunit file on cpanel.I scan my pc, Laravel files, phpunit but still getting error.

After 85% I am getting error.Would you help me in this?
Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution.
There are some issue in eval-stdin.php

C:\xampp\htdocs\myfirstlarvelproject\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Util\PHP\eval-stdin.php

**Before code**

```
<?phpeval('?>' . file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

**Replace the code**

```
<?php 
eval('?>' . file_get_contents('php://input'));
?>

I added space between <?php and eval and closed php tag ?>
```

And it's working for me.